# Constrain movement of HSlider Thumb by Accelerometer

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm moving an HSlider thumb via the accelerometer. The following code works fine. The problem, though, is that as I keep tilting the device, xSpeed continues to increment. This means that when I now tilt it the other way, the thumb doesn't move for a while -- since, depending on how long I was holding tilted in that intial direction, xSpeed has been going up and up.

So this works, but with the abovementioned flaw:

```
 private function readAcc(e:AccelerometerEvent):void
 {
    xSpeed -= e.accelerationX * 4; 
    myHSlider.dispatchEvent(new FlexEvent("valueCommit"));
    myHSlider.value += xSpeed;
 }
```

But what I want to do is to stop incrementing xSpeed once the hSlider.value == either the minimum or the maximum. Sounds simple, but when I put in if statements, they prevent the thumb from moving at all:

```
private function readA(e:AccelerometerEvent):void
{
if(h.minimum < h.value && h.maximum > h.value)
    {
    xSpeed -= e.accelerationX * 4; 
    h.dispatchEvent(new FlexEvent("valueCommit"));
    h.value += xSpeed;
    var lastSpeed:Number = xSpeed;
}
else if (h.value == h.minimum || h.value == h.maximum)
{
    xSpeed = lastSpeed;
    h.dispatchEvent(new FlexEvent("valueCommit"));
    h.value += xSpeed;
}
}
```

What should the logic be to make this work?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the value of `h.value` the first time this function is called?

Comment: You should trace all the values to understand what's going on

Comment: ...and I would move the declaration of the var lastSpeed outside the if statement...

Comment: Hi, yes, am tracing the values. I have it set to start at h.minimum, which is -54. (It goes from -54 to +54). What is interesting is that it traces the value out, if I tilt to the left, to less than -54, which is less than the minimum value. However, the thumb does not of course move.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to get at in my answer below.  If the value of the thumbslider is less than the minimum, then neither of your conditions will be true, and all of your code will be skipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, have figured this out and wanted to share it. The key is not to mess with setting the hslider's h.value. Rather, just set the x of the thumb, and let the value take care of itself. The accelerometer event calls a handler; in that handler create a moveThumb() function which will adjust that x. Then, from within the moveThumb() function, dispatch the valueCommit event so that the hslider will respond.

```
 private var xSpeed:Number;

 private function accUpdateHandler(e:AccelerometerEvent):void
 {
xSpeed -= e.accelerationX;
moveThumb();
 }

 private function moveThumb():void
 {
     var newX:Number = h.thumb.x + xSpeed;
     var newY:Number = h.thumb.y + ySpeed;
     if (newX < 0)
     {
         h.thumb.x = 0;
         xSpeed = 0;
     }
     else if (newX > h.width - h.thumb.width)
     {
         h.thumb.x = h.width - h.thumb.width;
         xSpeed = 0;
     }
     else
     {
         h.value += xSpeed;
     }
     h.dispatchEvent(new FlexEvent("valueCommit"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your slider value is exceeding the min or max limits when you add (or subtract) xSpeed.  Check for this, and subtract if the value is too high, or add if the value is too low.

```
// EDIT: Code modified to reflect most recent comment
if(h.minimum < h.value && h.maximum > h.value)
{
    xSpeed -= e.accelerationX * 4; 
    var lastSpeed:Number = xSpeed;

}
else if (h.value <= h.minimum )  
{
    xSpeed = 2;
}
else if ( h.value >= h.maximum )
{
    xSpeed = -2
}
h.value += xSpeed;
h.dispatchEvent(new FlexEvent("valueCommit"));
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't quite work either. Part of the problem is that once it hits h.minimum or h.maximum, it's stuck there. It doesn't move.

Comment: In the else conditions, try setting xSpeed to something other than lastSpeed. Try xSpeed = 2 at first.  Also, I just noticed a typo in my code above.  The first else should only check if the value is <= the minimum.

Comment: Actually, try just reversing the speed value (effectively reversing the direction of the slider)

Comment: Thanks. It still sticks when it's at the left end of the track. But I may have figured out what's wrong here. I think I need to manipulate h.thumb.x, not h.value. I'll report back if that works...

Comment: I'm wondering if lastSpeed is always winding up as a positive value, or 0.  If that's the case, then the slider will get stuck at one or both ends.  Try the code above as an experiment.

Comment: Yep, did that, and it sticks. Thing is, if I can accomplish the same thing by moving thumb.x, then it's the same as moving a ball. And the h.value will take care of itself.